# Laravel capturing foreign url on $request->fullURL() function

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a middleware that captures requests in/out. Here's the middleware code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $logger = "[" . $request->ip() . "]" . $request->method() . " => " . $request->fullUrl() . " [" . Carbon::now()->format("H:i:s") . "]; \nUser-Agent:" . $request->userAgent();

    log_routes($logger);

    return $next($request);
}

public function terminate($request, $response)
{
    $logger = "[" . $request->ip() . "]" . $request->method() . " <= " . $request->fullUrl() . " [" . Carbon::now()->format("H:i:s") . "]; \nUser-Agent:" . $request->userAgent();
    log_routes($logger);
}
```

normally this middleware output

```
[IP address]GET <= https://i-assume-this-should-be-my-url.com/endpoint [07:58:13];
User-Agent:User-Agent       App-Version:app version
[IP address]GET => https://i-assume-this-should-be-my-url.com/endpoint [07:58:13];
User-Agent:User-Agent       App-Version:app version
```

But somehow I don't know why it outputs foreign URL like this

```
[92.118.160.1]GET <= https://foreign-url.xyz [08:12:39];
User-Agent:NetSystemsResearch studies the availability of various services across the internet. Our website is netsystemsresearch.com   App-Version:Not Filled
[92.118.160.1]GET => https://foreign-url.xyz [08:12:39];
User-Agent:NetSystemsResearch studies the availability of various services across the internet. Our website is netsystemsresearch.com   App-Version:Not Filled
```

And another thing I'm really confused about is I use Cloudflare's firewall to block the incoming request if the User-Agent provided doesn't match with what I already defined. But this strange log shows there's the incoming request with unmatch user agent and can pass that firewall

Any help and explanation would be appreciated. Thank you so much